# How do you plot trajectory using read in values for x and y position?

Tags: python

I have tried to plot trajectory of a bouncing ball by reading in a file that contains 3 columns of data such as, t, x and y. t is time with x and y respectively being the positions of the ball. I read in the data as lists for each variable. I am somewhat new to python so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to take my x and y values and insert them into the theta list. I am getting a syntax error on the "plt.plot(t, 0)" line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as math
filename = 'NewTrackerVid_.txt'
infile = open(filename, 'r') # Open file for reading
line = infile.readline() # Read first line
# Read x and y coordinates from the file and store in lists
t = []
x = []
y = []

for line in infile:
    words = line.split() # Split line into words
    t.append(float(words[0]))
    x.append(float(words[1]))
    y.append(float(words[2]))

infile.close()

θ = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    θ.append(float(math.tan(y[i] / x[i])

plt.plot(t, θ)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('θ')
plt.title("Trajectory vs Time")
```

Comment: You need 2 more closing parentheses on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

What I gather you want to do is plot tan(y[i] / x[i]) for all x,y. Numpy and pandas will help this a lot!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(my_file_name.txt,columns=['t','x','y'])
df['theta']=np.tan((df['x']/df['y']))
df['theta'].plot()
```